# "В налоговую" или "в налоговой": как правильно?

Tags: согласование

Часто приходится писать разные тексты канцелярским языком, но что-то никак не могу определиться, как правильно согласовать: "Справка о постановке на учет в налоговую инспекцию" или "в налоговой инспекции"?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что за справка такая? Есть документ под названием "Свидетельство о постановке на учет в налоговом органе".

Comment: Не уверен, что речь о нем.
Справка - не свидетельство. 
Она может быть любой формы. Мало ли, посольство какое требует.

И потом, не все ж в России живут.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такие вещи плохо нормируются, поскольку у носителей канцелярита всегда своё мнение - и единственно правильное. 
Но вообще-то на учет ставят где, а не куда. 
Так что я за второй вариант: "на учет в налоговой инспекции".

Но: "Справка (о том-то и том-то) дана для предоставления в налоговую инспекцию."

Answer (score 3):

Если это не справка о зачислении в штат налоговых инспекторов или справка о постановке, отправляемая  в данную организацию, то постановка на учёт (где?) в налоговой инспекции. При форме *налоговую инспекцию* получается, что словосочетание отвечает на вопрос *куда?*, и будет указывать направление, а не место.

Сравните: был (где?) в городе (армии) - иду (куда?) в город (армию)